# Duplicated log events when deleting registry

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm currently working on a PoC ELK installation and I'd like to re-send every log line of a file which is registered in Filebeat for testing purposes.

This is what I do:

1. I stop Filebeat
2. I delete the index in Logstash through Kibana
3. I delete the Filebeat registry file
4. I start Filebeat

In Kibana I can see that twice as many events are there as log lines, and I can also see that every event is duplicated once.

Why is that?

Filebeat logs:

```
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 5.2.2
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Max Retries set to: 3
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Activated logstash as output plugin.
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Publisher name: anonymized
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Flush Interval set to: 1s
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Max Bulk Size set to: 2048
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO filebeat start running.
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO No registry file found under: /var/lib/filebeat/registry. Creating a new registry file.
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Loading registrar data from /var/lib/filebeat/registry
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO States Loaded from registrar: 0
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Loading Prospectors: 1
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Prospector with previous states loaded: 0
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Loading Prospectors completed. Number of prospectors: 1
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO All prospectors are initialised and running with 0 states to persist
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Starting Registrar
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Start sending events to output
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Starting prospector of type: log
2017-05-05T14:25:16+02:00 INFO Harvester started for file: /some/where/anonymized.log
2017-05-05T14:25:46+02:00 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: registrar.writes=2 libbeat.logstash.publish.read_bytes=54 libbeat.logstash.publish.write_bytes=32390 libbeat.logstash.published_and_acked_events=578 filebeat.harvester.running=1 registar.states.current=1 libbeat.logstash.call_count.PublishEvents=1 libbeat.publisher.published_events=578 publish.events=579 filebeat.harvester.started=1 registrar.states.update=579 filebeat.harvester.open_files=1
2017-05-05T14:26:16+02:00 INFO No non-zero metrics in the last 30s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the registry file created the problem.

Filebeat management the state of a file and the ACK of the event with the prospector(in memory) and with the Registry File(persisted in disk).

Please read the documentation [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/how-filebeat-works.html)

You can management the _id field of each event by yourself, so that any event that is duplicated (for any reason, even in production environment) will not have two of them in elasticsearch, but will update the event.

Create the following configuration in your logstash pipeline config file.

```
#if your logs don't have a unique ID, use the following to generate one
fingerprint{
        #with the message field or choose other(s) that can give you a  uniqueID
        source => ["message"]
        target => "LogID"
        key    => "something"
        method => "MD5"
        concatenate_sources => true
           }
 #in your output section 
    elasticsearch{
                     hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                     document_id => "%{LogID}"
                     index => "yourindex"
        }
```